# How to add a new column to a table formed from conditional statements?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a very simple query.

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
ID X Y
1 10 3
2 20 23
3 21 34
```

And I want to add a new column called Z which is equal to 1 if X is equal to or bigger than Y, or 0 otherwise.

My code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("XYZ.csv")
for x in data["X"]:
   if x >= data["Y"]:
      Data["Z"] = 1
   else:
      Data["Z"] = 0
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Maybe change `Data` to `data`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify exactly what you are asking. If the program produces an error, what is it and on what line. If the output is wrong, describe how and what it should look like. We're not mind-readers...

Comment: Try data['Z'] = np.where((data['X'] >= data['Y']), 1,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code is just fine. You simply capitalized your dataframe name as 'Data' instead of making it 'data'.

However, for efficient code, EdChum has a great answer above. Or another method similar to the for loop in efficiency but easier code to remember:

```
import numpy as np

data['Z'] = np.where(data.X >= data.Y, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks both, especially for the more efficient solutions

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without using a loop by using [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html) which means greater than or equal to and cast the boolean array to int using [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype):

```
In [119]:
df['Z'] = (df['X'].ge(df['Y'])).astype(int)
df

Out[119]:
   ID   X   Y  Z
0   1  10   3  1
1   2  20  23  0
2   3  21  34  0
```

Regarding your attempt:

```
for x in data["X"]:
   if x >= data["Y"]:
      Data["Z"] = 1
   else:
      Data["Z"] = 0
```

it wouldn't work, firstly you're using `Data` not `data`, even with that fixed you'd be comparing a scalar against an array so this would raise a warning as it's ambiguous to compare a scalar with an array, thirdly you're assigning the entire column so overwriting the column.

You need to access the index label which your loop didn't you can use [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html#pandas.Series.iteritems) to do this:

```
In [125]:
for idx, x in df["X"].iteritems():
    if x >= df['Y'].loc[idx]:
        df.loc[idx, 'Z'] = 1
    else:
        df.loc[idx, 'Z'] = 0
df

Out[125]:
   ID   X   Y  Z
0   1  10   3  1
1   2  20  23  0
2   3  21  34  0
```

But really this is unnecessary as there is a vectorised method here